# Yii2 Component class not loading config when instantiated

Tags: php, configuration, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have created a simple custom Component that extends from `yii\base\Component`.

```
namespace app\components\managers;

use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;

class HubspotDataManager extends Component
{
    public $hubspotApiKey;

    private $apiFactory;

    public function init()
    {
        if (empty($this->hubspotApiKey)) {
            throw new InvalidConfigException('Hubspot API Key cannot be empty.');
        }

        parent::init();

        // initialise Hubspot factory instance after configuration is applied
        $this->apiFactory = $this->getHubspotApiFactoryInstance();
    }

    public function getHubspotApiFactoryInstance()
    {
        return new \SevenShores\Hubspot\Factory([
            'key' => $this->hubspotApiKey,
            'oauth' => false, // default
            'base_url' => 'https://api.hubapi.com' // default
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have registered the component in my `config/web.php` application config, where I have also added a custom parameter.

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'hubspotDataManager' => [
        'class' => app\components\managers\HubspotDataManager::class,
        'hubspotApiKey' => 'mycustomkeystringhere',
    ],
    ...
],
```

However, I find that when I instantiate my component like so:

```
$hubspot = new HubspotDataManager();
```

this `hubspotApiKey` config parameter is not passed into the `__construct($config = [])` - `$config` is just an empty array, so in `init()` the config does not set the component `hubspotApiKey` property the the value of `hubspotApiKey` in the config, so accordingly I see this from my thrown exception:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
>
> Hubspot API Key cannot be empty.

However, if I call up the component like so:

```
Yii::$app->hubspotDataManager
```

it does pass this config variable in! Why is this? What extra legwork must I do to get the component to load it's application config data for standard class instantiation? I cannot find anything about this particular scenario in the docs.

NOTE: Using latest Yii2 version `2.0.15.1` using basic application template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an instance without using the Service Locator, the configuration is of course not known.

The flow is like this, `Yii::$app` is a Service Locator. It will pass the configuration to the Dependency Injector containter `Yii::$container`.

If you want to pass the config without using the Service Locator `Yii::$app`, you could set the container:

```
Yii::$container->set(app\components\managers\HubspotDataManager::class, [
    'hubspotApiKey' => 'mycustomkeystringhere',
]);
```

and

```
$hubspot = Yii::$container->get(app\components\managers\HubspotDataManager::class);
```

the result would be the same as using the service locator `Yii::$app`.

You could also instantiate the a new instance of the class like this and pass the configuration to it.

```
$hubspot = new HubspotDataManager([
    'hubspotApiKey' => 'mycustomkeystringhere',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation there. I guess [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-service-locator) helps some more too.

Comment: @ajmedway You can also use [`Yii::createObject(app\components\managers\HubspotDataManager::class)`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-baseyii#createObject()-detail).